# How to send UIImage data to Unity3d via a C# script and iOS plug-in?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to send UIImage data to Unity3d via a C# script and iOS plug-in? I need to set this image as a background to a button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I flowed the steps that are specified in this link:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/129937/ios-nsdata-to-unity-and-loadimage-from-the-data.html

& did it in this way: I have created a plug-in to save the image in directories folder

```
extern "C"
{
    const char*  _GetImage() 
    {
        NSLog(@"I am in Begin");
        UIImage *myUIImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Test.jpg"];
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myUIImage);
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test.jpg"]; //Add the file name
        NSLog(@"filePath %@",filePath);
        [imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
        return MakeStringCopy([filePath UTF8String]);
    }
}
```

& read the file path through C# script converted it into bytes and gave it to Texture2D.

> ```
> [DllImport ("__Internal")]    
> private static extern String _GetImage();
> ```

```
    public Texture2D texture2D;

    void Start () {
        texture2D = new Texture2D (200, 200);
        imagePath = GetImage();
        byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath);
        texture2D.LoadImage(imageBytes);
    }

    void OnGUI () {
        GUI.Button (new Rect(20,20,100,100),texture2D);
    }

    public static String GetImage() 
    {
        if (Application.platform != RuntimePlatform.OSXEditor)
        {
            return _GetImage();
        }   
        else
        {
             return @"Hello";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess, the same can be done backward - send image from unity to iOs app? Is it true?

Comment: You are calling UIImagePNGRepresentation but you are naming the file Test.jpg?